# How prove this inequality $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\cdots+\sqrt{i}}{i^2}\le\sqrt{2n-1}$

Tags: inequality

show that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\cdots+\sqrt{i}}{i^2}\le\sqrt{2n-1}$$

My try:
$$x\in(n-1,n)\Longrightarrow \sqrt{x}>\sqrt{n-1}$$
so
$$\int_{n-1}^{n}\sqrt{x}dx>\sqrt{n-1}$$
so
$$\dfrac{2}{3}n^{\frac{3}{2}}=\int_{0}^{n}\sqrt{x}dx>\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n-2}+\cdots+1$$
so
$$1+\sqrt{2}+\cdots+\sqrt{n}<\sqrt{n}+\dfrac{2}{3}n^{\frac{3}{2}}$$
But this not use.Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try induction. $P(1)$ is obvious.

$P(n) \Rightarrow P(n_+1)$.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\dfrac{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\cdots+\sqrt{i}}{i^2}\le\sqrt{2n-1} +\dfrac{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\cdots+\sqrt{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}$$

To complete the proof we need to show

$$\sqrt{2n-1} +\dfrac{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\cdots+\sqrt{n+1}}{(n+1)^2} \leq \sqrt{2n+1} \Leftrightarrow \\
\dfrac{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\cdots+\sqrt{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}  \leq \sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n-1} \Leftrightarrow \\
\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\cdots+\sqrt{n+1}  \leq (n+1)^2[ \sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n-1}] = \frac{2(n+1)^2}{\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n+1}} 
$$

Now, by your inequality we have

$$\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{2}+\cdots+\sqrt{n+1}  \leq \sqrt{n+1}+\frac{2}{3}(n+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

and the inequality

$$\sqrt{n+1}+\frac{2}{3}(n+1)^{\frac{3}{2}} \leq  \frac{2(n+1)^2}{2\sqrt{2n+1}} \leq  \frac{2(n+1)^2}{\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n+1}} $$

is easy to prove and completes the solution.

Comment: It's very nice.Thank you+1

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n-1} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n+1}}$?

Comment: @Alex Ty, fixed it. The last inequality should still be true since $\frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3} <1$, but it might fail for small $n$. This means that it needs to be checked manually up to a hopefully reasonable value :)